# Removing scary "Trust app" screen from Google Apps Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a web app that shows all the potholes that I have either filled, surveyed, or otherwise marked, which is written in Google Apps Script (the data store is a Google sheet, because ease of maintenance (easier to add pothole data and to modify faulty data)). The app is running as me, because if it is run as the end-user, that user would have to log in to their Google account (if they have one, and all for the sake of just seeing the map!).

Before I am ready to hand link to this map off to some end-users, I need to know what all I need to do to get rid of this scary "Trust app" screen that comes on every web app created with Google Apps Script. There seems to be a lot of hidden steps to it that I can't seem to get. I even bought a domain because of this, but haven't used it yet).

[image]

Comment: I tried verifying my (empty) domain via Google, and it failed.

Comment: Attempt to verify via my domain (which I have on content on yet) failed, and from the instructions, it seems to be ultimately be the case that I need to pay money for some GSuite account, just to take this shock-factor screen off my app.

Comment: One way to do this is, create a site on Sites.google.com (in new site). Then you can embed your google script app into the site. This seems to resolve the issue of trust app screen.

Comment: You would need a GSuite (aka paid) account for that.